# How to 'stretch' the cell of a column from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, cell

'stretch' may not be the most suitable way to put it, but I can't come up with any other word.

I have a data frame like this :

```
var1 <- c(rep(0, each=9),1999,rep(0, each=9),2000,rep(0, each=9),2001)
var2 <- c(rnorm(n=30))
df1 <- data.frame(var1,var2)
```

What I want to do is to replace every `0` from the column `var1` by the next number encountered in the column. Hence I want sthg like:

```
var1 <- c(rep(1999, each=10),rep(2000, each=10),rep(2001, each=10))
var2 <- c(rnorm(n=30))
df2 <- data.frame(var1,var2)
```

With `var2` having specific and ordered values I don't want to move around.

The thing is, the data frame is 500 000 rows long, so I would like not to find the row number of every `var1` different from `0`.

(it's likely that such question has been asked before, but since I couldn't find another word than 'stretch'...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `na.locf` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
#convert zeros to NA in order to use na.locf afterwards
df1$var1[df1$var1 == 0] <- NA
#fromLast carries the observations backwards
df1$var1 <- na.locf(df1$var1, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Out:

```
> df1
   var1        var2
1  1999 -0.04750614
2  1999 -0.35462388
3  1999  0.30700748
4  1999  1.09506443
5  1999 -0.61049306
6  1999  0.66687294
7  1999  0.54623236
8  1999 -0.04848903
9  1999 -0.56502719
10 1999  0.08067966
11 2000 -0.05474748
12 2000  0.27380898
13 2000 -0.21283353
14 2000 -0.89820808
15 2000 -0.18752047
16 2000  0.21827094
17 2000  0.56370895
18 2000 -1.21738551
19 2000 -0.61426847
20 2000 -1.34144736
21 2001 -0.52697208
22 2001  0.90209640
23 2001 -0.52040468
24 2001 -0.37432746
25 2001 -0.21218776
26 2001  0.88372231
27 2001  0.54274394
28 2001  0.06127087
29 2001  0.04263164
30 2001  0.52294204
```

Comment: it seems to be very close to working, but I get this:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, YEAR, value = c(1987, 1987, 1987, 1987,  :  replacement has 507957 rows, data has 507988

Comment: Probably your last value (i.e. last row) is NA and it has nothing to carry backwards. Set the last value to what you want to be rolled over and it will work.